# How to write and implement your own function

Tags: c++, function, sqrt

I need to write my own sqrt function: double my_sqrt_1(double n)
How would I go about doing this? At first I tried putting this outside of "int main()":

```
double my_sqrt_1(double n)
{
    int x = 1;
    x = (x + n / x) / 2;
}
```

I then put this:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a value ";
    cin >> my_sqrt_1;
    cout << '\n' << x;
}
```

I also tried:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a value ";
    cin >> my_sqrt_1;
    cout << '\n' << my_sqrt_1;
}
```

None of this worked though. I'm probably doing this completely wrong, but it made sense in my head.

Comment: You call a function with `()`, but you are treating it like a `variable`. Looks like you need to start with some basics.

Comment: Please define what you mean when you say "none of this worked". I can see what is wrong, but it is a good discipline for you to write down the error messages. At that point, once you are compelled to write them down, you will also be forced to read them.

Comment: You *do* know how to call functions, don't you? Haven't you called any functions before? If it's a function you made or some function someone else made doesn't matter, calling a function is calling a function. Also, you need to actually *return* something from the function if you say you will.

Comment: Time for a book or a tutorial...

Comment: Google is your friend here.

Comment: Search the web for "C++ Integer Division", and also "Computer Scientist Floating Point".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I'm probably doing this completely wrong ..."*

Sorry to say that, but yes.

You need a variable to receive input, and call your function passing that variable

```
int main() {
    cout << "Please enter a value ";
    double myNumber;
    cin >> myNumber;
    cout << '\n' << my_sqrt1(myNumber) << endl;
}
```

Also your function is supposed to return the result of the calculation

```
double my_sqrt_1(double n) {
    double x = 1.0;
 // ^^^^^^      ^^
    x = (x + n / x) / 2.0;
                    // ^^
    return x; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Comment: Thank you for not being too harsh on me and my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Joe De nada. And welcome to the [tag:c++] shark tank :-D ...

Comment: Could you explain something to me though?
In the function, it says 'double n'
Then it calls n during the math part, what is n? I never gave it a value or anything, so why is it in there?

Comment: @Joe _"In the function, it says 'double n"_ And what's your concern with it? Function parameters can be named arbitrarily in c++, no matter what the variable names are, that will be passed to the function when calling it.

Comment: Oh wait. Never mind, me being an idiot once again.

I'm starting to think I should just not post anything anymore.

Comment: @Joe _"me being an idiot"_ Well, I didn't say that, and didn't meant so. We've all been starting out at some point. But you really should get some good basic c++ tutorial, before asking questions on SO. This might not be the best place for learning about the bolts & nuts.